# MongoDB - How to do subqueries in aggregation

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am trying to add a field to an aggregation called `friendshipStatus` and it determines whether the user is a friend of the requester or not.

I have this whole query:

```
[
  {
    $match: (query) ? query : {}
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      friendshipStatus: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $in: [vierweruserName || '', "$friends"]
          },
          then: "friend",
          else: {
            $cond: {
              if: {
                $in: [vierweruserName || '', "$friendRequests"]
              },
              then: "requested",
              else: "none"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      firstName: 1,
      lastName: 1,
      userDescription: 1,
      userName: 1,
      imgURL: 1,
      coverURL: 1,
      friendshipStatus: 1 // Include the new field in the output
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: 50
  }
]
```

And I want to modify this `addField` stage to check if the user name is in the requester's `friendRequests` array or not (that would happen if he sent the requester a friend request)

```
{
  $addFields: {
    friendshipStatus: {
      $cond: {
        if: {
          $in: [vierweruserName || '', "$friends"]
        },
        then: "friend",
        else: {
          $cond: {
            if: {
              $in: [vierweruserName || '', "$friendRequests"]
            },
            then: "requested",
            else: "none"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am expecting the code should also add the `friendshipStatus` as 'requested' if the user is in the array of `friendRequests` in the `viewerUserName` document. I wonder if I can do a subquery in the `addFields` stage to get the viewerUserName document and then search it or if there is another way.

Sample document:

```
{
    "_id": "65034fed2153ebff85f30554",
    "userName": "minamelad232",
    "firstName": "mina",
    "lastName": "melad",
    "password": "$2b$10$Sr/cWOWwtAC9AQpHHLjFfuD3TKLIFvjd89QwgIJdz6cMB.rvWFeJy",
    "userDescription": "No description",
    "friends": ["minamelad123"],
    "friendRequests": ["markosami123"],
    "imgURL": "http://res.cloudinary.com/dik65evmf/image/upload/v1694726404/widgetUpl...",
    "coverURL": "http://res.cloudinary.com/dik65evmf/image/upload/v1694715952/widgetUpl...",
    "influence": 0,
    "feedOffset": 0,
    "commentsOffset": 0,
    "friendRequestsOffset": 0,
    "__v": 42    
}
```

Sample output:

```
{
    "userName": "minamelad232",
    "firstName": "mina",
    "lastName": "melad",
    "userDescription": "No description",
    "imgURL": "http://res.cloudinary.com/dik65evmf/image/upload/v1694726404/widgetUpload/qbegll5tmhumijplqkek.jpg",
    "coverURL": "http://res.cloudinary.com/dik65evmf/image/upload/v1694715952/widgetUpload/f61ztmyvln0c5p0ei1db.png",
    "friendshipStatus": "none"
}
```

Comment: Can you provide sample document and expected result? Thanks.

Comment: Post the sample document in the question post instead of comment for better readability.

Comment: Suggested reading for aggregations   https://www.practical-mongodb-aggregations.com

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but could you provide any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that these are the sample (minimal) documents:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "userName": "Alex",
    "friends": [],
    "friendRequests": [
      //"may"
      
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
    "userName": "May",
    "friends": [],
    "friendRequests": [
      "Alex"
    ]
  }
]
```

As mentioned you need to search the viewer's `friendRequests`, this requires to self join the collection with `userName: vierwerUsename`

1. `$lookup` - Search the document in the same collection with `userName: vierwerUsename` and return the document in the array as `viewer`.
2. `$addField` - Would recommend using `$switch` operator for handling multiple conditions instead of nested `$cond`. For the third condition, you should match the condition with the `userName` in the document does existed in the `friendRequest` of the `viewer`.

```
{
    $lookup: {
      from: "collection", // replace with your collection name
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                vieweruserName || '',
                "$userName"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "viewer"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      friendshipStatus: {
        $switch: {
          branches: [
            {
              case: {
                $in: [
                  vieweruserName || '',
                  "$friends"
                ]
              },
              then: "friend"
            },
            {
              case: {
                $in: [
                  vieweruserName || '',
                  "$friendRequests"
                ]
              },
              then: "requested"
            },
            {
              case: {
                $in: [
                  "$userName",
                  {
                    $getField: {
                      field: "friendRequests",
                      input: {
                        $arrayElemAt: [
                          "$viewer",
                          0
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              },
              then: "requested"
            }
          ],
          default: "none"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lWaIYPXCtSX)

Answer (score 0):

In your current query, you are checking if the viewerUserName exists in the $friends array or the $friendRequests array to determine the friendshipStatus. If you want to check if the viewerUserName exists in the friendRequests array of the viewerUserName document itself, you can modify the query as follows:

```
[
  {
    $match: (query) ? query : {}
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      friendshipStatus: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $in: [vierweruserName || '', "$friends"]
          },
          then: "friend",
          else: {
            $cond: {
              if: {
                $in: [vierweruserName || '', "$friendRequests"]
              },
              then: "requested",
              else: {
                $cond: {
                  if: {
                    $in: [vierweruserName || '', "$$ROOT.friendRequests"] // Check in viewerUserName's own friendRequests array
                  },
                  then: "requested",
                  else: "none"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      firstName: 1,
      lastName: 1,
      userDescription: 1,
      userName: 1,
      imgURL: 1,
      coverURL: 1,
      friendshipStatus: 1 // Include the new field in the output
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: 50
  }
]
```

In the modified query, I added an additional $cond expression inside the else block of the second $cond expression. This checks if viewerUserName exists in the friendRequests array of the viewerUserName document itself ($$ROOT.friendRequests). If it does, then the friendshipStatus will be set as "requested". Otherwise, it will be set as "none".

Comment: Why `$$ROOT`?`$$ROOT.friendRequests` is equivalent to `friendRequests`. Don't see any reason that add another `$cond` to check the same condition and set the value for same condition.